# SQL tables relations

Tags: database-design

i'm making a MySQL data base , my tables are: **users**, **activitylog**, **activitytype**.

to avoid repetitions i thought about including activitytype in each activity which is logged into activitylog table, for example:

1-Activity Types Table

2-Activity Log Table

[image]

Is it an interesting model if yes how could i do it ?

Comment: How could i do it ?

Comment: Was my answer correct ? If so marked as !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Wozniak form what i can see you need the sql syntax t build this structure ! to do so use the syntax belew :

```
create table Activity_Types(
activity_type_id in,
activity_name varchar(20),
PRIMARY KEY (activity_type_id)
);


create table Activity_Log(
activity_id int,
user_id id,
activity_type_fk id,
activity_date date,
PRIMARY KEY (activity_id),
FOREIGN KEY (activity_type_fk) REFERENCES Activity_Types(activity_type_id)
);
```

Where foreign key that makes the relation is hold on the Activiy_log table under the activity_type_fk column. 
 to join this tables just use this columns !